# Conditional Gaussian Comparison Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am trying to prove a conditional gaussian comparison inequality. Specifically, I am looking to prove that for two $n$-dimensional Gaussian variables $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ and $Y_1,\cdots,Y_n$, assume that $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\mathbb{E}[Y_i]=0$, $\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]=\mathbb{E}[Y_i^2]$, $\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j]\leq \mathbb{E}[Y_iY_j]$, we have for all $u_1,\cdots, u_{n-1} < 0$:
$$\mathbb{P}\left[\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} \{X_i \geq u_i \} \mid  X_n=0 \right]\leq \mathbb{P}\left[\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} \{Y_i \geq u_i \}\mid  Y_n=0 \right]$$
Intuitively this makes sense because $Y_i$ are more correlated with each other and thus should have a lower tail probability of being all far away from zero, but I have having a hard time proving it rigorously.

I know Kahane's inequality and thought it can get me there, but the fact that I am conditioning on $X_n/Y_n=0$ makes a direct application difficult, so I was wondering if I am overlooking an easier approach.

Comment: I think the inequality should go the opposite way, if it is true at all. Check the case where $X_n,Y_n$ are independent of the first $n-1$ components and $u_1 = ... = u_{n-1} = 0$. In this setting you should be able to use either Kahane's inequality or Slepian's inequality.

Comment: @MattWerenski in that case the statement is true in the way that it is written. Slepian's lemma usual form takes $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap X_i \leq u_i)\leq \mathbb{P}(\bigcap Y_i \leq u_i)$ for all $u_i$, and you can just take $X_i \to -X_i$ to get the result.

Comment: Ahh I see you are correct, I accidentally flipped a sign in my calculations. The typical form I see for Slepian uses the condition $\mathbb{E}(X_i - X_j)^2 \leq \mathbb{E}(Y_i - Y_j)^2$ which is equivalent to $\mathbb{E}(X_iX_j) \geq \mathbb{E}(Y_iY_j)$ (opposite to your condition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false if you include $u_i=0$, here is a counterexample.

Take $n=2$, let $X_1,Y_1,Y_2$ be independent standard Gaussians, and $X_2=-X_1$.
All have mean zero and unit variance, and $\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2]=-1<0=\mathbb{E}[Y_1Y_2]$.
Moreover, for $u_1=0$,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[X_1\geq 0|X_2=0\right]=1
>\frac{1}{2}=\mathbb{P}\left[Y_1\geq 0|Y_2=0\right]
$$

---

*Edit:*
For $u_i<0$, the same counterexample works:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[X_1\geq u_1|X_2=0\right]
\geq\mathbb{P}\left[X_1= 0|X_2=0\right]
 =1
>\mathbb{P}\left[Y_1\geq u_1\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[Y_1\geq u_1|Y_2=0\right]
$$

Comment: Is it true if we do not include 0 then?

Comment: @MichaelLi the same counterexample works, see the edit to my answer.